# Pitfalls of two redis-servers sharing the same dump.rdb file

Tags: redis

I need to clear a concept. I have two redis servers running on a single VM. Server#1 connects via TCP, server#2 connects via a UNIX socket. I'm on the cusp of converting the TCP server to UNIX as well.

The `conf` file for the first instance specifies the following location to save the DB dump: `/var/lib/redis/dump.rdb`.

The `conf` file for the second instance specifies exactly the same location and file as well.

Does this imply that the saved DB file contains data for *both redis servers*? I need to ensure that this particular scenario doesn't make me lose data when I restart the servers. Being a beginner, I'd really like some expert opinion on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what this means is that one server overwrites the rdb file of the other. Use the configuration file to specify a different dump file for each server.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in Itamar. I've changed the `dbfilename` to `dump2.rdb` for the second redis-server in its config. Is there a way to have this setting take force without restarting the server?

Comment: Sure - just do `config set dbfilename "dump2.rdb` to apply it in runtime... You can verify afterwards by doing a `BGSAVE` and seeing the file come into existence

Comment: Great. Btw just wondering: the aforementioned overwriting happens even when there are no namespace collisions (for keys) between the two redis-servers?

Comment: The dump is just that - Redis overwrites the file (if it exists) with the current data. No regards to whatever is in it is given.

Comment: Curiously enough, for the past hour or so, only `dump2.rdb` has been updating now, with `dump.rdb` entirely unchanged (down to the very byte) since I used `config set`. It's a live project with decent traffic, and both redis-servers have keys that often get updated. I think I might have misconfigured something here.